# Change font size in list of log messages

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I enter TortiseSVN settings for font size in

General → Dialogs 1 → Font for log messages

...then I will only change font size of commit messages, not the list of commits or the list of affected files.

Is there some way of changing all the font sizes? Preferrably without tampering with system font size.

Comment: Being able to use a monospaced font in log messages list could benefit by aligning messages easily.